# Multiple HNQ widgets don't work simultaneously

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets, widgets

Having two or more widgets, I am facing a problem where only the last updated instance of a widget is clickable. 
I can refresh any widget with the refresh button, not open SE app by tapping the question.

Can be simulated by refreshing one widget and clicking the question on the second one. The SE app will not open.

Happens on various versions of Android (4.4, 5, 6.0.1) and various launchers, so it's not only a problem with my device

Comment: @meatball you're right. That guy wrote it the way I was unable to find it. Mine is a duplicate then.